# Initializing an array of structs within a class definition

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a struct that creates nodes for a BST like this

```
struct BSTNode{
    int data;
    BSTNode *left;
    BSTNode *right;
};
```

and I need to create an array of these root nodes inside of a class

```
class HashBST{
public:
    bool lookup(int);
    void insert(int);
    bool remove(int);
    float getLoad();
//private:
    int hash(int);

    BSTNode *table[1019];
    float load;
    int occupied = 0;
    int tableSize = 1019;
};
```

from there I want to be able to check and see if a BST node has an entry or not. Initially I tried setting the `data` int to -1 in the struct definition, but in my array in the class, each node had a garbage data value.

Is there a way to set all of the data values to -1, or more ideally, set all the pointers in the `table` array to `NULL` until something is stored in them?

Comment: Have you tried adding a default constructor to `BSTNode`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is there a way to set all of the data values to -1,

There isn't because the design of your node implies a specific design of the hash table. Since you have nodes, that implies that you use [separate chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) for hash table collision resolution.

And that means your bucket array `table` needs to be initialized with null pointers, otherwise it contains indeterminate values:

```
BSTNode* table[1019] = {}; // Zero-initialize buckets.
```

And then `lookup` member function is going to look like:

```
bool HashBST::lookup(int value) {
    unsigned value_hash = hash(value); // Hash must be an unsigned value.
    unsigned index = value_hash % tableSize;
    for(BSTNode* node = table[index]; node; node = node->right) {
        if(node->data == value)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

In a more advanced version the bucket table should be just a pointer `BSTNode* table;` which gets initialized with the result of `new[]` and the size of the referred table is in `tableSize`.

Comment: Great, thank you! That first line of code you provided did the trick!

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would do it in a C++ friendly way:

Firstly, convert `table` to `std::vector`:

`std::vector<BSTNode*> table`

Create a constructor for `HashBst` that initializes your `std::vector<T*>` with all nullptr values.

`HashBST() : table(1019) {} //table items are all nullptr`